# Dragable and Resizable div with angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, resizable

I am trying to create resizable div containers and also they are dragable.

I used Angular material Drag and Drop and [angular resizable element](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-resizable-element#documentation)

Here is workaround
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-syurbs?embed=1&file=src/polyfills.ts

But when I apply both, I can drag but I can't resize.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-41rqyo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

How can I achieve both in one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cdkDragHandle` directive on an icon or button
`<button cdkDragHandle>Drag Icon</button>`

See the whole api here https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api

Example: https://stackblitz.com/angular/jamgbjgmynoq

Comment: I am asking how to achieve "drag and drop" and "resizable"

Comment: Yes, when you use a Handler to drag the element, then you will be able to resize it. There is no other way to do that in Angular Material

Answer (score 2):

An Easy way to Create a Draggable & Resizable Angular Component

You can achieve the draggable and resizable component yourself without Angular Material. You need to do it in three steps.

1. Make a div resizable
2. Link mouse movement to the div’s position to make it draggable/movable
3. Add boundary restrictions to your mouse movements

The core of step (1) is to calculate the new div size by subtract mouse position(coordinates) and div’s position(left&top positions)

Step (2) requires calculating the movement of your mouse and add the same amount of movements to your div’s top & left position.

Step (3) you will need to calculate the outside container’s top, right, bottom and left boundaries’ position.

To get div element’s position, you need to use Web API - Element.getBoundingClientRect()

To get mouse positions you need to add a mouse move listener to the window and a mouse down listener to the div element itself.

I have written a post about how to achieve these three steps with further explanations and graphics. You can have a look if you are still not clear about how to achieve it.

[Create a Resizable and Draggable Angular Component](https://link.medium.com/qkd73P2dA8)

Comment: do you have the repository? The are some parts that I don't understand

Comment: Hi @RicardoSanchezSantos, yes, please find the code here:https://github.com/theideasaler/angular-resizable-draggable

Comment: It is possible to combine drag & resize. see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

You can add a hitbox element inside of your draggable, it should be slightly smaller and perfectly centered inside of your target element.

[image]

The blue area is the hitbox element.
Now, apply a `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events on the hitbox element respectively, and disable the dragging whenever your mouse is not on top of the hitbox element.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering how to use resizable behaviour alongside draggable, feel free to use (or extend) my simple solution:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-brtlte?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example based on the docs from "Angular Material".

I've added these 2 lines to original example (see cdk-drag-drop-handle-example.css)

```css
overflow: auto;
resize: both;
```

[Here is the example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gwk8gb-apg5h1?file=src/app/cdk-drag-drop-handle-example.css)

[Here is the original code + docs](https://v13.material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview)
see the "Customizing the drag area using a handle" secion